# How do we set time in vhdl simulation for an fpga kit having clock of 100 MHz?

Tags: vhdl

We are writing a code in vhdl. How do we set time in vhdl simulation for an fpga kit having clock of 100 MHz? Should we set it to 10ns(10 nano seconds) for effective viewing of results? Where should we do it?...In the encircled portion of the first figure or the encircled portion of the second figure?

first figure:[image]

second figure:

[image]

And kindly tell us the significance of the encircled portion in fist and second figures respectively.

Comment: A clock should have a period of 1/f of the frequency. Its a simulation, you get to decide what the clock frequency\period is. You can ether force it like is shown in the second fixture, or develop a vhdl testfixture that connects to your toplevel diagram and simulates things in the outside world like your clock or other I/O stimulus vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-write-testbench.html or google vhdl testbench

Comment: Please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first figure your circled is the simulation running time. Basically what it means is by clicking on the button next to it you'll run the simulation for 10ns.

The second screenshot shows a tool to create an internal clock signal.
I'm not familiar with the software you're using, but in my own test benches, I'm used to simulate a clock signal with the following snippet of code:

```
p_clk : process
begin
    clk <= '0';
    while true loop
        wait for CLK_PERIOD/2;
        clk <= not clk;
    end loop;
    wait;
end process p_clk;
```

With `CLK_PERIOD` being a constant that define as you please, in your case you should have:
    `constant CLK_PERIOD : time := 1 sec / 10e9;`

EDIT:
Although the dialog box you have seems to be serving the same purpose. You can read about it on Xilinx website, [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_4/ism_db_clock.htm)

You can also try to "force clock" on your signal by right-clicking on it, and select "Force Clock"

Answer (score 2):

Your question illustrates that you are mixing up the meaning of "clock" in different contexts in your design and it is indeed important to correct this understanding.

1. Your FPGA has a technological limit: depending on the part and on the design it will have a maximum frequency of operation.  This frequency is generally given after synthesis (or compilation as it may be called in the FPGA context).
   Typically, the more combinational logic you have from one flip flop to another, the slower your FPGA can run.  Let's call this the max FPGA clock.
2. Your FPGA kit (referring to the hardware evaluation board) seems to have a preset onboard system clock set to 100MHz.  If the system clock is smaller or equal to the max FPGA clock, everything is fine.  Otherwise your circuit may not work.
3. Your simulation clock can be chosen independently of the max FPGA clock and the system clock, but you'll typically *choose* to set it to the system clock because you normally want your simulation to behave like your physical system.  Generally this clock will be defined in your testbench (VHDL/Verilog/...), but you can also choose to define it interactively through a signal generator.
4. Your simulation environment allows you to define some signals (2nd figure). Even if the popup says "define clock", this does not mean that it is a clock to your system, it just says that you are defining your signal like a clock.  With a clock meaning that your signal is repeated from period to period with the signal setting to the leading edge value first and the trailing edge value next according to the timing specifications that you set.  You can apply this "clock type" to any signal, even if the signal is not a clock.
5. There are some other timing definitions in your simulator as indicated in another answer/comment - this can be the simulation time step, the amount of time to simulation when you ask to continue the simulation, etc.  The "10 us" of your first figure corresponds to 1000 cycles of your system clock (10ns period).  It does not define your clock, it means that your simulation will advance by 10us at a time.  The way you define your clock will not influence this.